# Recording digital piano sound

Tags: recording, digital-piano, homerecording, cable

I want to record (sound, not MIDI) from my Yamaha P115. I am just wondering what is the optimal way.

I have tried doing it simply with my phone, without a cable, and as expected it sucks. I live in noisy Kolkata, making the ambient noise impossible during the day. The phone (OnePlus 3) mic cracks even when it is relatively quiet.

So I was thinking of connecting it with cable to the phone. Or connecting the piano to a PC and record through a software (it seems Audacity will serve the purpose). But then someone said "audio interface". I looked into the stuff and got daunted by TRS, XLR & RCA. P115 has two 1/8" headphone o/p and two Aux Out (L & L/R). There's also USB to Host, but I guess that's for MIDI.

Given this, what are my setup options?

(I feel this isn't a perfect question. So, apologies.)

Comment: What level of audio quality are you looking for?

Comment: Start with your PC and Audacity. Just connect the audio out from the keyboard to the "aux" audio input on the PC (not the "mic" input). If that doesn't give you good enough quality, *then* consider spending money on something more "optimal".

Comment: alephzero, I don't have an aux input on my laptop, just a mic input. and what do you mean by "audio out" from the keyboard - the 1/8" headphone out, or the "aux out" (which I believe uses the RCA cable)?
And if latter, should I use only the Mono (L/R), or both L & R,, in which case what kind of cable/ jack required?

ScottM, I haven't thought much about quality. I am no performer. But a late beginner. Will record for my own listening for improvement. What do YOU suggest?

Comment: realised that my laptop does not have mic in :-((
what do I do now? :-0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestions here, slightly shortened discussion.

Electrical pianos sound a lot better in stereo than in mono in my experience. So, when possible try to record both left and right signal. More about that later.

The piano has aux out-s that are perfect for recording. And you possibly have a sound input on your computer. This is wastly better than using the microphone in a noise surrounding.

So, possibly, you could get a cable and be done with it. But there are actually two problems (or even more) with that approach.

.1 The computer most probably wants a microphone level signal (read very weak). The piano outputs line level signal on the aux out (read medium strong). I have never tried doing this kind of thing, so I cannot really tell, but I would expect the result using only a cable to be mostly distorsion.

.2 The computer most probably only has a mono input (one signal), and as I said, the piano sound better using stereo (ie two channels).

My suggestion is to get a really cheap USB audio interface. It should cost you about 30 to 50 USD or so for an interface with two instrument inputs ( 1/4 inch ). You will need a usb cable and two 1/4 mono cables. We tend not to recommend specific products here, but a quick search on internet should give you a lot to choose from, simply pick one. Even better, when possible, visit your local friendly music shop and spend a few dollars extra and getting help.

Comment: Thank you gheliquist!  I was looking at Behringer UM2. Not sure where can I fit two RCA cables (from the L&R Aux Out) in that one. Looks like it has only one XLR line 1. Or should I take the 1/8" headphone out? Would appreciate any advice.

Comment: Check the manual. The UM2 has two line in. Line 1 in is in the middle of the left kombination contact.  Line 2 has its own contact. Use two mono cables, 1/4 inch*  mono contacts at both ends. Connect from Aux L and Aux R on the piano to Line 1 and Line 2 on the UM2.   *) 1/4 inch ( quarter inch ) mono cables is the same type of cable used for electrical guitars. No RCA contacts here.

Comment: It has the following inputs: 1x XLR/TRS combo jack mic/line input
1x 1/4" (6.3 mm) instrument input

Comment: realised that my laptop does not have mic in :-(( what do I do now? :-0

Comment: The UM2 will work perfectly.

Comment: So I take the UM2 USB output to one of the laptop USB ports?

Comment: Right. Then two cables, both ends 1/4 inch (6,3 mm) mono between the UM2 and the piano.

Comment: I have recorded with my PC's combination jack set to "line in" (i.e. "mic in", but stereo) and got full range recordings that passed a blind A/B test with other producers.  It's worth trying the mic in on your PC if there is one.